# MySQL query with optional left join

Tags: mysql

i have the following database relations:

**user** 1:n **survey** 1:n **statement** 1:n **user_response** n:1 **user**

i need to query all statements which don't have a relation to a user_response or where the field user_response.closed = 1 of a given user-, and a given statement-id.

I don't really get it...

**EDIT**

Here's an export of my database. For example i have the survey-id 1 and user-id 1. I need all statements of the survey with the id 1, which don't have a response of the user with the id 1, or where the response of the user is not closed.

So my result should be 'Statement 1' (because user_response.closed = 0) and 'Statement 2' (because the user with id 1 didn't give a response).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `statement` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `survey_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `2` (`survey_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `statement` (`id`, `title`, `survey_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Statement 1', 1),
(2, 'Statement 2', 1),
(3, 'Statement 1', 2),
(4, 'Statement 1', 3);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `survey` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `1` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `survey` (`id`, `title`, `user_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Survey 1', 1),
(2, 'Survey 2', 1),
(3, 'Survey 3', 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Max'),
(2, 'Peter');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_response` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `closed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `statement_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `3` (`statement_id`),
  KEY `4` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `user_response` (`id`, `value`, `closed`, `statement_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
(1, 50, 0, 1, 1),
(2, 20, 0, 4, 2);

ALTER TABLE `statement`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `2` FOREIGN KEY (`survey_id`) REFERENCES `survey` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_BBA66ED9A94F7BC` FOREIGN KEY (`survey_id`) REFERENCES `survey` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `survey`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_AD5F9BFC9395C3F3` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `user_response`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `3` FOREIGN KEY (`statement_id`) REFERENCES `statement` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `4` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`);
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Show some data samples. What do you have what do you expect? What is the database structure?

Comment: Just a second, i'll give you a workbench screenshot...

Comment: Screenshot? Noooooo. Proper DDLs please!

Comment: Sorry, first time i write here in the mysql section... I edited my question!